# please object: a way to handle rewrite map urls that end with "/"

Tags: .net, iis, mod-rewrite

I would like to have your opinion and suggestion regarding the solution to this specific problem:

I have a rewritemap that takes care of a lot of vanity URLs, problem is, users may enter that vanity URL ending with a "/" or no "/", the matching does not occur in both cases, only one is matched, so I decided to create a rule first, that reduces the "/" then let the rewrite map take care of the matching... here is how it looks:

```
<rewrite>
 <rules>
  <rule name="ReduceLast" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="^.+(?=/+$)"/>
   <action type="Redirect" url="{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
  </rule>
  <rule name="Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url=".*" />
   <conditions>
    <add input="{StaticRedirects:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="False" redirectType="Permanent" />
  </rule>
 </rules>
 <rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">
   <add key="/australia/download" value="http://www.example.com/australia/trial-software.aspx" />
  </rewriteMap>
 </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: rediculous! i found the first bug, iis adds a trailing slash by default when it finds the url, absolute nightmare!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that wasnt a great solution especially that trailing slashes are added by iis, here is a better workaround (notice the trailing slash in the map key)

```
<rewrite>
<rules>

    <rule name="Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions>
      <add input="{StaticRedirects:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="False" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect Rule2" stopProcessing="true">
     <match url=".*" />
     <conditions>
      <add input="{StaticRedirects:{URL}/}" pattern="(.+)" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="False" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
<rewriteMaps>  
<rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">  
 <add key="/australia/download/" value="http://www.example.com/australia/trial-software.aspx" />  
</rewriteMap> 
</rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: very supportive this site is, im overwhelmed

Answer (score 2):

Following on from the accepted answer it's should also be possible to the same with less lines of code:

```
<rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect Rule" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{StaticRedirects:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
            <add input="{StaticRedirects:{URL}/}" pattern="(.+)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="False" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
      <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="StaticRedirects">
          <add key="/australia/download/" value="http://www.example.com/australia/trial-software.aspx" />
        </rewriteMap>
      </rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Very nice! You could also omit the `trackAllCaptures="false"` option since this is the default value.